# git - Can you clone via HTTPS even if SSH-style git@github is used

Tags: git, ssh, git-submodules

I'm trying to clone a git repository which has submodules via `git submodule update --init --recursive`. These submodules all use "git@github.com:foo/bar.git" URLs. Unfortunately, my work place is preventing SSH URLs from their firewall. I can, however, clone via HTTPS, with no problems.

As mentioned, the submodule URLs are hard-coded in the repository to use SSH. Is there a way to tell git to clone these submodule repositories using HTTPS without instead of SSH making any direct modifications to the git repository?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`git config --global url.<base>.insteadOf`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-urlltbasegtinsteadOf) to substitute URLs on the fly. Something like

```
git config --global url.https://github.com/.insteadOf git@github.com:
```

(Please note the colon at the end; it's neccessary to map `git@github.com:user/repo.git` to `https://github.com/user/repo.git`).

See more examples in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-submodules%5D+insteadof

Comment: This looks like it should work. But in my case I think it's still somehow picking up SSH (even on my home machine). e.g. `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvv" git submodule update --init --recursive` still prints out SSH information even after running your suggested command

Comment: Wait, apparently if `sslVerify = false` is in ~/.gitconfig` then it fails. I removed that line and now it appears to be working! Thank you for your help!