# How to define private dependencies to allow ssh with https fallback (pip, setuptools)

Tags: python, github, pip, setuptools

I have a Python project with private dependencies. That being said, I try to have the easiest installation procedure possible.

With https and double authentification, this is not easy. I personnally use an SSH key, but not everyone in the project has it.

So in my **setup.cfg**, I have something like this:

```
install_requires =
  photutils
  numpy
  mydep @ git+ssh://git@github.com/mydep.git#egg=mydep
```

But for production, I need to use:

```
install_requires =
  photutils
  numpy
  mydep @ git+https://github.com/mydep.git#egg=mydep
```

which is a pain for me, because that's not how I use it by default. Is there a way to have a third dependency declaration that uses **ssh** by default, but fallback to **https** if you don't have an ssh access? I couldn't find such a syntax on stackoverflow or pip documentation.

Comment: You can replace git URLs on the fly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66537201/7976758

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to have a third dependency declaration that uses ssh by default, but fallback to https if you don't have an ssh access?

Not without a script, which would test ssh access, and, as comment, would switch to https if ssh is not available.

The switch would use:

```
git config --global url.git+https://.insteadOf git+ssh://git
```

But again, this needs to be wrapped in a script which would test for SSH access first.

Comment: Thanks for your insight ! People don't necessarily have the git repository when they install it, not sure it would work. This seems to confirm there's no way to handle that at the pip level.

Comment: @Autiwa How `pip` would  work regarding any Git operation, if `git` itself is not already installed?

Comment: I'm not sure pip need Git just to install a package, it just retrieve a .tar.gz from the web and install it. No need for any git commands for just that, don't you think?

Comment: @Autiwa OK. I am more familiar withe dependencies expresses as `git+...`