git submodule Redirection
Is it possible to configure git to checkout submodules from a different host, say dev.azure.com instead of the url, say github.com, stored in the repo?
I'd like to hit a mirror of the repos instead of the normal ones, but I don't want to have to change the main repo itself.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55245054/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/66537201/7976758 . You can make Git replace URLs on the fly. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-submodules%5D+insteadof

git config --global url.https://dev.azure.com/path1/to/submodule.insteadOf https://github.com/user/repo.git

Are you hitting the main repo from the different host too, or just the submodules? If those whole lot moved together, you should consider using relative URLs for the submodules instead of absolute ones, e.g., url = ../submodulename.git in .gitmodules would fetch the submodule from the same account on whichever server you cloned from. I've written about this before here but I don't know if this is relevant  to you or not, so leaving this only as a comment.
